# In inline ckeditor mode space can't be allowed

Tags: ckeditor

I have been using ckeditor since long time. But when I used inline mode of ckeditor it does not allow to use space in content. I mean what a wired problem isn't it? Anyone have the solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a bare bones example of the page that hosts ckeditor and how you instantiate it?

Comment: CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true; 
CKEDITOR.inline( 'editor1' );